# Read long single-line text file to JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a long single-line text file looking like this:

```
{"attributes":{"fieldAttrs":"{\"request_querystring\":{\"count\":6},\"server_duration\":{

...

"version":"iidfwu83"}
```

That spans one single line in a text file `myjson.json`.

I know from a database that this whole object is a legit deeply nested JSON object.

How do I read it into a Python JSON object?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: looks like doubly encoded json, you can decode it, but it would be much better to fix the code that created it in the first place.